# Launching the Settings/Market from a widget

Tags: android, widget, settings, google-play, launch

How would I go about launching the Settings menu/the Market from a widget. Ive tried using a code and using the Settings/Market package name, but neither of them will open. Heres the code I'm using:

```
String packageName = "com.package";
String className = "com.package.MainActivity";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, className));
startActivity(intent);
```

Also, the phone I'm testing on runs HTC Sense, if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea how to start the Market app (I'm not even sure if it's possible) but to launch the Settings Activity, try...

```
Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
startActivity(i);
```

You'll need the following import...

```
import android.provider.Settings;
```

Comment: I get the following errors, "ACTION_SETTINGS cannot be resolved or is not a field" and "the return type for the method startActivity is missing" and "i cannot be resolved to a type" Im very new to all of this so I'm just learning so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @natehoch96: Sorry, I don't know. `startActivity` doesn't have a return type as such (it's defined as void). If you make sure the `import` I mentioned is in the import block of your Activity code file and simply replace the 5 lines you posted in your original question with the 2 lines I posted then things 'should' work.

Comment: so I managed to figure out the "ACTION_SETTINGS" one, it needs to be "android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS" and then the startActivity one i fixed by adding void in front of it which i figured out from you saying its defined as void. but where i run into problems is, first of all i cant import "android.provider.Settings" but i dont think that matters now that i added it to my intent? maybe? and then the startActivity(i) is still giving me complications, and i also receiver a syntax error on the semicolon in the first line. any help would be greatly appreciated